# How to insert a value in pgsql where the row to be insert is equal to the number of array passed in function?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to pass an array in function in postgres and want to insert rows in a table 'application_upload_demand' by selecting value from 'application_upload'. The rows inserted into table 'application_upload_demand' will be equal to the element of arrays. I have no idea about array in pgsql. Please suggest any thing-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.application_upload_demand_insert(
    appl_nos character varying,
    appl_num character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare appl_nos character varying;array1 text[];arrayTxt text[];
BEGIN

FOREACH appl_nos SLICE i IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
      array1[i] = appl_nos[i];
   END LOOP;

INSERT INTO application_upload_demand(file_name, file_type, documentid, doctype, file_upload, appl_no, upload_date, inspector_remarks,lab_code,div_code, dist_code,  loginid )   
select file_name, file_type, documentid, doctype, file_upload, appl_no, upload_date, inspector_remarks,lab_code,div_code, dist_code, loginid from application_upload 
where sno =ANY(arr) and appl_no = appl_num;

END
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.application_upload_demand_insert(character varying, character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

My php code is->

```
try{
        $con->beginTransaction();

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
       $sno=$_POST['checkbox'];
       $pginsstmt12="SELECT public.application_upload_demand_insert(?,?)"; 
       $newinsdata = $con->prepare($pginsstmt12);           
       $newinsdata->bindparam(1,$sno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $newinsdata->bindparam(2,$hidden_appl_no,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $newinsdata->execute(); 
    }
    $con->commit();
    }catch(Exception $ex) {
                    $con->rollBack();
                    $error=$ex->getMessage();

            }
```

Comment: where is php code

Comment: I added the php code.